# Add hover effect on social icons in header?

Tags: css

i want make an hover effect social icons in header like this website http://lalomacd.com.mx/2013/

Can i get html code and css, please.

Regards,

Erwan

Comment: What have you tired and what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b93gjruc/light/)

```
    .header-social{
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.fa {
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}

/*--Padding to help round out the icon's circle border--*/
span.fa-facebook {
  padding: 5px 8px;
}
span.fa-play {
  padding: 5px 6px 5px 8px;
}

/*--Hover Effects for each icon--*/
.fa:hover{
    color:#FFF;
    transition: background 1s ease;
}
.fa-facebook:hover{
    background:#3b5998;
}
.fa-twitter:hover{
    background: #55acee;
}
.fa-google-plus:hover{
    background: #dd4b39;
}
.fa-play:hover{
    background: #cd201f;
}
```

And if you wanna learn more about it you can refer the below link.

[Link](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css3-rollover-social-media-icons/)

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked!